# Versions of Choice in categories

Tags: category-theory

A naive question, but here goes ....

In his original ETCS paper, Lawvere states a categorial version of choice for sets in this form: "If the domain of $f$ has elements, then there exists $g$ such that $fgf = f$". So let's say, generalizing

(1) A category has Choice-1 iff for any $f\colon X \to Y$ where $X \not\cong 0$ [with $0$ initial], there exists a $g \colon Y \to X$ such that  $f \circ g \circ f = f$.

Another more familiar version of choice for sets is that any surjection has a right inverse (or left inverse, depending on your preferred handedness convention!). Generalizing, let's say

(2) A category has Choice-2 iff for any epic $f\colon X \to Y$ there exists a $g \colon Y \to X$ such that  $f \circ g = 1_Y$.

Forgive a senior moment, but I'm embarrassingly unclear about the conditions -- the weakest/most natural/nicest conditions? --  under which a category which has Choice-2 has Lawvere's Choice-1. Is there a standard story about this which I've missed?

Comment: Why does choice 1 implies choice 2? Ok my bad I'm dumb I did not read the "epic"

Comment: What exactly is $0$ in choice-1? An initial object?

Comment: @S.C. yes ... clarified!

Comment: So I think there is a property in some specific Krull Schmidt categories (maybe you need an exact structure where epics and monics are not really epics and monics) where you can factorize each morphism $f$ into $g \circ h$ with $g$ epic and $h$ monic, this could help maybe?

Comment: @JulesBesson I think there *ought* to be simpler story. After all, Lawvere & Rosebrugh in effect set my query as an *exercise* -- hence my feeling that I'm just having a senior moment here ;-)

Comment: It might be sufficient to have an epi-mono factorization structure on the category, plus the condition that every subobject has a complement (in such a way that the subobject lattices become boolean algebras), plus the condition that every non-initial object has a global section (i.e. a morphism from the final object to it).  Granted, those are probably some pretty strong conditions...

Comment: OOOPS! Initially I wrote that if a category has Choice-1, it trivially has Choice-2, which was just silly, as we only get the trivial implication for the cases where ≇0! But the remaining case is OK in a topos, say: for then any arrow 0→ is monic, so an epic :0→ will be iso, since a topos is balanced, and so  will have the required inverse